# Mockito equivalent of EasyMockRule?

Tags: junit, mockito, easymock

I find very little reason to use EasyMock, with Mockito available.

However, when I have a class with a million dependencies, I prefer annotation syntax - Mockito @Mock/@InjectMocks or EasyMock @Mock/@TestSubject.

As far as I can tell from poking around, with Mockito I have to use MockitoJUnitRunner, or MockitoAnnotations.

MockitoJUnitRunner supports field injection, but as far as I can see, the latter requires constructor/setter injection. When I need to use a different runner, and don't want to add constructors or setters to my production code for testing, I seem to be stuck with EasyMockRule.

Does Mockito provide an equivalent, to allow non-Mockito runners and field injection?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [org.mockito.junit.MockitoJunit.rule()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnit.html).

```
@Rule
public final MethodRule mockito = MockitoJunit.rule();
```

Comment: hmm...  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/creation/CglibMockMaker

Comment: Which version of Mockito do you use?

Comment: I believe that was 1.10.17, the first version with MockitoJUnit. Looks like 2.0 isn't out the door yet.